# Pandas: find the column value based on searching the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
```

The dataframe `df` looks like

```
      A      B  C   D
 0  foo    one  0   0
 1  bar    one  1   2
 2  foo    two  2   4
 3  bar  three  3   6
 4  foo    two  4   8
 5  bar    two  5  10
 6  foo    one  6  12
 7  foo  three  7  14
```

How can I write the code if I want to get the value of `D` when `C` equals to 1? In other words, how can I return the `D` value which is `2` when `C = 1`?

Comment: have you tried slicing the dataframe with `.loc` ? `df.loc[df['C'].eq(1), 'D']`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and use `.loc`:

```
result = df.loc[df.C == 1, "D"]
```

alternative equivalent syntax as noted in the comments:

```
result = df.loc[df['C'].eq(1), 'D']
```

While you can "chain operations, such as `df[df.C == 1]["D"]` will get you the correct result, you will encounter poor performance as your data scales.

Answer (score -1):

You can search the data frame based on condition (here "C" == 1) and then get the column by index lookup

This will return a Series, you will have to use `.values` to get the NumPy array

```
>>> df
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
1  bar    one  1   2
2  foo    two  2   4
3  bar  three  3   6
4  foo    two  4   8
5  bar    two  5  10
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14
>>> df[df["C"] == 1]["D"].values
array([2])
>>> df[df["C"] == 1]["D"].values[0]
2
>>>
```

References

- [Selecting rows in pandas DataFrame based on conditions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/)